# How can we get compiler generated field value by reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a function in C#, which created a lambda delegate:

```
static public class PortableDemo
{
    static public void PortableKernel(int offset)
    {
        PortableUtil.Foo(() => Console.WriteLine("1"));
    }
```

I analyze the IL code, and it looks like:

```
IsStatic: true
             00000000 nop             
             00000001 ldsfld          System.Action <>9__0_0
             00000006 dup             
             00000007 brtrue.s        L_0020 /* = 32 (rel.: 23) */
             00000009 pop
```

So, it loads a static field which name is `<>9__0_0`. This is a compiler generated field, and from dotPeek, I can confirm it is there by in gray color (means compiler generated private field).

Now the question is, I can get the `FieldInfo` of that field, but I try to get the value of it by `fieldInfo.GetValue(null)`, and it always returns `null`. So how can I get that value?

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Please include a precise, detailed explanation of what you've tried, and what difficulty you're having getting the code to work. It is hardly clear from the code you've posted that the field in question is indeed static. If it is indeed static, it's not clearly from what you've posted why calling `GetValue(null)` would return a null value.

Answer (score 4):

> I can get the `FieldInfo` of that field, but I try to get the value of it by `fieldInfo.GetValue(null)`, and it always returns `null`. So how can I get that value?

You are getting the value. The field is null at the time you are asking for the value of the field. Null is a legal value for a field of reference type.

What you are looking at here is a compiler-generated field that is an implementation detail; that field is not required to have any particular value that is of any particular use to you at any particular time. You shouldn't be touching it.

If you want to know why the field is null: fields are null until they are initialized. You've decompiled the code; you can see that there is a branch that tests the field value for nullity. Read the rest of the code and see where the field is assigned to a non-null value. The field is not initialized until it needs to be.